# Prove $ \left |\sin(x) - x + \frac{x^3}{3!} \right | < \frac{4}{15}$

Tags: analysis

Prove $ \left |\sin(x) - x + \dfrac{x^3}{3!} \right | < \dfrac{4}{15}$ $\forall x \in [-2,2]$

By Maclaurin's formula and Lagrange's remainder we have $\sin(x)  = x - \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + \dfrac{\sin(\xi)}{5!}x^5$ for some $0<\xi<2$

subbing this in we get $\left|\dfrac{\sin(\xi)}{5!}x^5 \right| \leq \left |\dfrac{x^5}{5!} \right| \leq \dfrac{2^5}{5!} = \dfrac{4}{15}$, but the question has $<$ rather than $\leq$ - where have I done wrong?

edit: thinking the $\cos(\xi)$ should be there rather than $\sin(\xi)$

Comment: Perhaps the estimate $| \sin(\xi) | \le 1$ is too weak.  Can you argue that $\xi \ne \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ (the only values in $[-2, 2]$ where $| \sin x | = 1$)?

Comment: You haven't done anything *wrong*: you just have to do more. You'll have to analyze something more carefully; e.g. as @Sammy mentions. as an aside, another way to do the problem is to recognize that the remainder of the Taylor series is an alternating series whose terms are strictly decreasing in magnitude.

Comment: keep in mind that $sin(x) = x-{x^3 \over 3!} + {x^5 \over 120}$ **-** ${x^7 \over 7!}$ since $\frac{x^5}{5!}= 4/15$ for x = 2 if you subtract something than it would be lower ;-)

Comment: @Hurkyl Could you please explain your alternate method for solving the problem?

Comment: There is equality in $\left |\dfrac{x^5}{5!} \right| \leq \dfrac{2^5}{5!}$ only when ... and check those cases separately.

Comment: @GEdar What do you mean? $|\frac{x^5}{5!}| \leq \frac{2^5}{5!} $$\forall x \in [-2,2]$

Comment: @SammyBlack On second thoughts, shouldn't $\sin(\xi)$ actually be $\cos(\xi)$ which then solves all our problems?

Answer (score 2):

Use the exact form of the Taylor formula:
$$
\sin x - x  + \frac{x^3}3 = \int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^4}{4!}\cos(t) dt
\\
\left| \sin x - x  + \frac{x^3}3 \right| = 
\left| \int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^4}{4!}\cos(t) dt \right|
\le\int_0^x  \left| \frac{(x-t)^4}{4!}\cos(t) \right|dt \\
\le\int_0^x \left| \frac{(x-t)^4}{4!} \right|dt 
= \int_0^x \frac{t^4}{4!} dt = \frac{2^5}{5!} 
$$
Now if there is equality anywhere, every inequality becomes an equality, but considering the first implies that $x=0$, and the last implies that $x=2$.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I've never seen this exact form before, so I guess we have yet to cover it.

Comment: just do a few integrations by parts :)

Answer (score 2):

From the Leibniz rule it is known that, if the sequence of $\frac{x^4}{5!},\frac{x^6}{7!},\frac{x^8}{9!},...$ is decreasing, which is the case for $x^2<6\cdot7=42$, $|x|\le6$ to get a round number, then
$$
0\le\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}
\le \frac{\sin x}{x}-1+\frac{x^2}{3!}
\le\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+\frac{x^8}{9!}
=\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{72}\right).
$$
Since under the assumed restrictions $1-\frac{x^2}{72}\ge\frac12$, we get
$$
\left|\sin x-x+\frac{x^3}{3!}\right|\le\frac{|x|^5}{5!}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{84}\right)<\frac{|x|^5}{5!}
$$
for $0<|x|<6$.